# Exploiting a crypto backdoor based on a polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

At a capture-the-flag competition during the weekend, there was a task that involved the following polynomial over the field $F = \mathbb{F}_P$ of integers modulo $P = 571787215471557516425591$ (yes, it's a prime).

$f(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$

With

$A = 645355246, B = 17587344665267433444$ and $C = 16443808597681565772$.

Now basically the challenge is, given an initial $x \in F$ and an $n \in \mathbb{N}$, to compute $f^{(n)}(x)$, i.e. the $n$-th composition of $f$ with itself. More precisely, we have $f^{(0)}(x) = x$ and inductively, $f^{(k+1)}(x) = f(f^{(k)}(x))$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

If $A, B, C$ and $P$ were completely arbitrary, it seems like the recurrence would be hard to solve efficiently in $o(n)$ (I would be happy to hear about general ways to solve quadratic recurrences though). However, apparently they were chosen to make a much more efficient computation possible, thus adding a backdoor to the crypto protocol built on top of it.

I happen to have access to [the source code](https://gist.github.com/5lipper/d6363e436f08f12f0bbb) of a program that solves this task.

Basically it computes $y = Ax + \frac{B}{2} \pmod P$, then applies some magical function $z = G(y, n+1)$, then transforms the result back to $f^{(n)}(x) = (z - \frac{B}{2}) / A$.

Now unfortunately I don't understand what $G$ does on a conceptual level. More importantly, I have *no* idea how one would come up with that solution in the first place.

Can anybody shed some light on what's the background here? How the algorithm works and maybe what some generic technique is that would help us derive those relations?

Comment: The $Ax+B/2$ part, at least is easy to understand: If you set $y_n=Ax_n+B/2$, then the recurrence $x_{n+1}=Ax_n^2+Bx_n+C$ turns into $y_{n+1}=y_n^2 + (C+B/2-B^2)$, where the first and second coefficients are $1$ and $0$. So the magic in $G$ just needs to be a general solution to iterating a function of the form $y\mapsto y^2+K$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see, that's helpful :)

Comment: ... and in this case it turns out that $K = -2$.

Comment: @Robert: Hmm, I get something horrible. Ah, it should be $K=AC+B/2-(B/2)^2$, then it fits.